Where does an eccentric 1:1 tidal-locked planet reach its maximum longitudinal libration?
I have been studying longitudinal libration for several days now, but have a question about where libration occurs in a planet's orbit.
For example, let us say that planet Alice has an eccentricity of .1 and a semi major axis of 1 AU around the star Bob. This gives the planet an apoapsis of 1.1 AU and an periapsis of .9 AU. Bob itself has a mass of 1 solar mass, giving Alice an orbital period of 1 year. The longitudinal libration reaches a approximate maximum extent of 11.5 degrees eastward and westward depending on where the planet is during its orbit, from 2arcsin(x) where x is the eccentricity.
My question is, how would I go about calculating where exactly does this maximum libration occur in its orbit?
